# Entry price change when bar is closed in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I am using the close value as the entry price but when the bar is closed the entry price will get the value of the closed bar. The entry price is being changed in this code below. Can someone halp me please?

```
if(bought_long == false and barssince(crossover(ema9, ema20)) == 0 and low[2] < open and low[2] < 
    low[1] and ema9 > ema20)
       stop_loss_long := low[2]
       entry_price_long := close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the price of `open` on the bar following your condition:

```
cond bought_long == false and barssince(crossover(ema9, ema20)) == 0 and low[2] < open and low[2] < low[1] and ema9 > ema20
if cond[1]
       stop_loss_long := low[3]
       entry_price_long := open
```